# What does Quota in Usage Plan limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Is it the quota for every API call containing an API key? or does it include API calls with no API key on them?

Comment: For every API call, quota is being used. Without api key, you may not be able to make a call

Comment: @OsamaKhalid we only have 1 API call that requires an API key and this API returns a token that should be used in the other APIs

Comment: The other APIs requires the token but not an API key. The token btw is returned by Cognito.

Comment: I think using the token to make calls to api is also considered a call. Retrieving token first means that the call is authenticated.

Comment: So, would that mean that those API calls that only require the token would still be affected by the quota set in API gateway?

Comment: Look, first we are making an API call to retrieve token, then other API calls to make some requests to our API. All of these are API calls. Token specifies that the call is authenticated. 
And yes, quota will be affected by each and every call to api.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid Yeah, I see. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we are making an API call to retrieve token, then other API calls to make some requests to our API. All of these are API calls. Token specifies that the call is authenticated. And yes, quota will be affected by each and every call to API.